# Add to statusline

Tags: vimrc, statusline

I'm using [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin for my statusline.

Now I want to install [kite](https://kite.com/) which suggests adding a section to the statusline.

I tried adding using:

```
set statusline+=%{kite#statusline()}
```

but that just messes up my statusline.

How do I do it properly?

Comment: See [`:help airline-funcrefs`](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/v0.11/doc/airline.txt#L1570), I think you can use that to extend airline and include the kite information... @ChristianBrabandt is one of the maintainers of airline and is active on this site, he might have better advice here.

Comment: I stopped using Airline, but IIRC it was possible to swap existing sections out for new functions (or extend, as the case may be)